# Grouping data starting with specific number in R

Tags: r, grouping

I am sorry if the title is incomprehensible. I have a data as shown below; 1, 2, 3.. are months of various years. And I want to gather months separately for a and l.

```
               a         l
1-2006  3.498939 0.8523857
1-2007 14.801777 0.2457656
1-2008  6.893728 0.5381691
2-2006  2.090962 0.6764694
2-2007  9.192913 0.8740950
2-2016  5.059505 1.1761113
```

Structure of data is;

```
 data<-structure(list(a = c(3.49893890760882, 14.8017770056402, 6.89372828391484, 
                           2.0909624091048, 9.19291324208917, 5.05950526612261, 13.1570625271881, 
                           14.9570662205959, 7.72453112976811, 12.9331892673657  
                           ), l = c(0.852385662732809, 
                                                                      0.245765570168399, 0.538169092055646, 0.676469362818052, 0.874095005203713, 
                                                                      1.17611132212132, 0.76857056091243, 0.622533767341579, 0.9562200838363, 
                                                                      1.10064589903771, 0.85863722854391  
                                      )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1-2006", 
                                                                                                                              "1-2007", "1-2008",   

                                                                                                                              "2-2006", "2-2007", 

                                                                                                                              "2-2016",   
                                                                                                                               "3-2015", "3-2016", "3-2017", "3-2018"
                                                                                                                             ))
```

For example; I want to gather all `january (1-2005, 1-2006..)` and march data(3-2012, 3-2015..) data for a and also for l. Like this one:

```
        january_a 
1-2006  3.498939 
1-2007 14.801777 
1-2008  6.893728 

        january_l
1-2006  0.8523857
1-2007  0.2457656
1-2008  0.5381691 


        march_a 
3-2012  9.192913 
3-2015  5.059505 

        march_l
3-2012  0.8740950
3-2015  1.1761113
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a column which contains only the numerical prefix, and then split on that:

```
data$prefix <- sub("^(\\d+).*$", "\\1", row.names(data))
data_a <- split(data[,"a"], data$prefix)
data_a

$`1`
[1]  3.498939 14.801777  6.893728

$`2`
[1] 2.090962 9.192913 5.059505
```

**Data:**

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(3.498939, 14.801777, 6.893728, 2.090962, 9.192913, 5.059505),
                   l=c(0.8523857, 0.2457656, 0.5381691, 0.6764694, 0.8740950, 1.1761113))
row.names(data) <- c("1-2006", "1-2007", "1-2008", "2-2006", "2-2007", "2-2016")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another variation that you can try using `tidyverse` which returns a list of dataframes, where every element has a combination of month and `"a"` or `"l"`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  rownames_to_column('date') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -date) %>%
  separate(date, c('month', 'year'), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
  group_split(month, name)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  date   month year  name  value
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 1-2006 1     2006  a      3.50
#2 1-2007 1     2007  a     14.8 
#3 1-2008 1     2008  a      6.89

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  date   month year  name  value
#  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 1-2006 1     2006  l     0.852
#2 1-2007 1     2007  l     0.246
#3 1-2008 1     2008  l     0.538
#...
#...
```

This has some additional columns to uniquely identify values which you can remove if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `group_split`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
   select(rn, a) %>%
   group_split(rn = str_remove(rn, '-.*'), keep = FALSE) %>% 
   map(flatten_dbl)
#[[1]]
#[1]  3.498939 14.801777  6.893728

#[[2]]
#[1] 2.090962 9.192913 5.059505
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(a=c(3.498939, 14.801777, 6.893728, 2.090962, 9.192913, 5.059505),
                   l=c(0.8523857, 0.2457656, 0.5381691, 0.6764694, 0.8740950, 1.1761113))
row.names(data) <- c("1-2006", "1-2007", "1-2008", "2-2006", "2-2007", "2-2016")
```